# Stop Service from outside

Tags: android, service

I have created my own service in my application. It works fine...
The service is started when someone changes a preference.
Now I want to stop the service, when the preference gets changed back to another value.
What is the best way to realize this?
The service could be active on the device for several days...So I do not know how
to access on methods in the service to stop it.

Comment: I don't understand how you can start a service when someone changes a preference but you don't know how to stop the service again. How do you start the service? Show some code and somebody might be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [stopService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29) when the Preference changes its value.

Comment: I thought that I can´t access the service anymore...But now i saw that the parameter of stopService is (intent)...it is so obvious and is working fine now...thanks